# How to add custom class names to elements in a Handlebars template using a helper function?

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I have a sample object with which I am trying to make a navigation bar, with each `li` to have a custom class name like this:

```
<ul>
      <li class="mainLink1">
          <a href="m1/home.html">home</a>
          <ul class="subParent1">
              <li class="sublink1"><a href="s1/home.html">s1/home</a></li>
              <li class="sublink2"><a href="s2/home.html">s2/home</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="mainLink2">
         <a href="m2/service.html">service</a>
         <ul class="subParent2">
             <li class="sublink1"><a href="s1/service.html">s1/service</a></li>
             <li class="sublink2"><a href="s2/service.html">s2/service</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

I know that all these class names have to be generated by a helper function, but I'm confused because I could not get proper results. Here is my try.

My html with template:

```
<div id="navigate"></div>

<script type="text/handlebars-x-template" id="menu">
    <ul>
        {{#list}}
           <li><a href="{{link}}">{{name}}</a></li>
            {{#if list.sub}}
                <ul>
                    {{#each this}}
                       <li><a href="{{link}}">{{name}}</a></li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            {{/if}}
        {{/list}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

My helper function and implementation:

```
var obj = [{"name":"home","link":"m1/home.html","sub":[{"sname":"s1/home","slink":"s1/home.html"},{"sname":"s/home","slink2":"s2/home.html"}]},{"name":"service","link":"m2/service.html","sub":[{"sname":"s1/service","slink":"s1/service.html"},{"sname":"s/service","slink2":"s2/service.html"}]}]

Handlebars.registerHelper("list", function(context, option){
    console.log(context, option);
})

var temp = Handlebars.compile($("#menu").html());
var html = $("#navigate").html(temp(obj));
```

I agree that my try is very bad. Any help to correct it and make to apply the class names using @index property.

[A fiddle for the above.](http://jsfiddle.net/knjWb/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your `custom helper` has no context , this is nothing but the context object that is passed in with the name of the helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("list", function(context, option) {
```

So by default `context` argument will be `options`

Context is the one that is passed to the helper

```
 {{#list this}}
          ^------ This is the context
```

Next your object is an Array of objects, so your approach will not work. You would require to either change the way you are using the template structure, or iterate over the object and pass in a single object to your template..

And there is no `key` called `list` that holds the `sub` property

```
{{#if list.sub}}
```

Supposed to be

```
{{#if this.sub}}
```

**Code**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("list", function(context, options) {
    // Return fn from options that will pass in the object to
    // the truthy function
    console.log(context + ' :: ' + options); 
    return options.fn(this);
})

// Compile your template
var temp = Handlebars.compile($("#menu").html());
var $ul = $('#navigate > ul');
// Append it to the container after iterating over array of objects
for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
    $ul.append(temp(obj[i]));
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/knjWb/2/)**

**UPDATE**

Then in that case you would not require the template helper in the first place. Just use the `each` loop and `@index` to iterate over the lists.

**Template**

```
<script type="text/handlebars-x-template" id="menu">
    {{#each this}}
        <li class="mainLink{{@index}}">
            <a href="{{link}}">{{name}}</a>
        {{#if this.sub}}
            <ul class="subParent{{@index}}">
                {{#each this.sub}}
                    <li class="sublink{{@index}}"><a href="{{slink}}">{{sname}}</a></li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        {{/if}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/knjWb/4/)**

Comment: What do you mean dynamically ?

Comment: i just want to add the class names to each of the "li" - elements, using the helper function. (to add the styles and icons). - see my html in my question as a first info